# Is a template engine really necessary when creating post requests?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Im in the process of creating a simple form, that post data from user input when submitted. For the life of me I cant find a way to render the html form without a template engine. For example with a template engine like pug in my app.js file I can just put:

```
app.post("/form", (req, res) => { res.render("form"); });
```

and it will render the form page for me so that I can test it on my local server. Is there any way to render my form when its not a template file like "form.pug". What if I dont want to use a template engine, and just want to render my "form.html" ?

Answer (score 1):

No, You need template engine when you want to generate html with getting some data from backend and if you not want to write too much html then you can use template engine.

```js
app.post('/form', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('views/success.html', {root: __dirname })
});
```